# Colpitts Oscillator, hard time finding values to use

Tags: capacitor, analog, inductor, oscillator

I am having a hard time trying to find a logical way to find values for capacitors and inductor to build this circuit (colpitts oscillator)
I read this great [tutorial](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/oscillator/colpitts.html)
and I have simulated the circuit and its works just fine. Now I would like to build it with components I have. 
I have a lot of capacitors too many values to name but I do not happen to have the values used in the example on the website. So I ask is there a way to manipulate the formulas or something that is not catching my eye as far as choosing capacitor and inductor values?

I know that: 
Xc1 + Xc2 = XL

So in my mind I think ok let me choose two caps and from there figure out what 
inductor I need, but in order to that i need a resonant frequency to derive my capacitive reactance values, but i cannot do that without my inductance value. So i have 3 unknowns capacitor values, inductor value and resonant frequency value. With the catch that Xc1 +Xc2 = Xl @ resonant freq. To make it even more fun the feed back given by C1/C2 cannot be too big or too small.
[image]

Comment: If you don't care what the resonant frequency is, just use the values you have on hand.  The simulator will then show you the resulting frequency.  If you do care, then that is one less unknown.

Comment: @Barry Yes I have been pondering the issue for a while after I wrote this, and I have found that it is quite east to first pick a freq and an inductance, which gives me an inductive reactance (Xl), given that reactance I can pick two capacitors who's Xc add up to it. I think i was over thinking the problem

Comment: You will have lots of Miller Input Capacity, looking into the base.